# Онлайн чат: получение ответа собеседника

Tags: javascript, чат

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как чаще всего делают автополучение ответа собеседника?

То есть, два пользователя, переписываются, как в vk.com, например. Как скрипт должен узнать, что второй пользователь отправил сообщение?

Как я понимаю, только ставить таймер, чтобы он через время посылал запрос, ответил ли второй пользователь, или нет.

Возможно, есть другие варианты получения ответа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [Comet-технологии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(программирование)).

Есть несколько способов:

- pooling (постоянные запросы, которые указали вы)
- long-pooling (длинные запросы)
- forever-frame (бесконечный iframe)
- XHR-запросы (вроде не везде работает)
- webSocket (пока только черновой вариант)

что-то подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://javascript.ru/AJAX/comet) или лучше поискать боле подробную информацию.

Comment: Преимущества WAMP по сравнению с Comet:

 * реализация паттерна Pub/Sub;
 * RPC и routed RPC;
 * открытый стандарт.

Comment: polling. нет там никаких пулов.

Answer (score 1):

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws/), о котором был отличный доклад ([слайды](http://t.co/eC0rr7FIl7)) на недавнем MoscowJS.

Расшифровывается не как *Windows/Apache/MySQL/Php*, а как **Web Application Messaging Protocol**  : )